# ggplot - How to create a heatmap that calculates and displays ratios?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to create a heatmap with ggplot where the fill represents the magnitude of some ratios. I currently have a table which looks like this:

```
 company survey  type        value
* <chr>   <chr>   <chr>       <dbl>
1 Raps    S1_2014 Revenue 282576375
2 Raps    S2_2014 Revenue 654413143
3 Raps    S3_2014 Revenue 365753902
```

My ggplot code is:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=survey, y=survey)) +
   geom_tile(aes(fill=value/value))
```

The result graph looks like this:
[image: My heatmap]

As you can see, there are blanks in the graph where the surveys do not interact with themselves (ie. S1_2014 and S3_2014). Can I code these intersections into my ggplot call? Or do I need to wrangle the data? If I do need to wrangle, how would I go about that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - ggplot will only plot the data you give it. I'm actually really surprised that `value / value` gives you anything other than 1. You can cross join your data and then plot:

```
dd = merge(df1[c(2, 4)], df1[c(2, 4)], all = T, by = NULL)

ggplot(dd, aes(survey.x, survey.y, fill = value.x / value.y)) + 
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

This way you can also control (and tell) which way the ratio goes.

---

Using this as input:

```
df1 = read.table(text = "company survey  type        value
1 Raps    S1_2014 Revenue 282576375
2 Raps    S2_2014 Revenue 654413143
3 Raps    S3_2014 Revenue 365753902", header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks! As for the values in my graph, it seems I uploaded the wrong file. In the one shown fill=value, which is why there aren't any 1s.